# Construct String from Regexp

Tags: regex, string, go

I've trying to find out a way to construct `string` data from a compiled `*regexp.Regexp` with given `interface{}` array. For example:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<word>\w+)\s*(?P<num>\d+)`)
```

I want to construct a `string` from the structure found in `re` by a `string` and a `int` data which may be received as `interface{}`.

Can't figure out how I can do that in Go. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many regular expressions match an infinite amount of strings. Do you want to generate them all? In any particular order? Your problem isn't really well-defined.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

Such a library, often called [Xeger](https://github.com/bluezio/xeger), exists for many languages, including go. However, this one is called [regen](https://github.com/nilium/regen): It's a tool to generate random strings from Go/RE2 regular expressions.

Here's an example:

```
$ regen -n 3 '[a-z]{6,12}(\+[a-z]{6,12})?@[a-z]{6,16}(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}'
iprbph+gqastu@regegzqa.msp
abxfcomj@uyzxrgj.kld.pp
vzqdrmiz@ewdhsdzshvvxjk.pi
```

> Essentially, all regen does is parse the regular expressions it's
>   given and iterate over the tree produced by regexp/syntax and attempt
>   to generate strings based on the ops described by its results. This
>   could probably be optimized further by compiling the resulting Regexp
>   into a Prog, but I didn't feel like this was worthwhile when it's a
>   very small tool.

Some additional information can be
 found at https://godoc.org/go.spiff.io/regen.

Answer (score 0):

While technically not impossible this is a **huge** amount of work.

Go regexp package compiles regular expressions into bytecode programs that are then executed to search strings. De-compiling this bytecode back into a regular expression is not impossible but quite difficult and moreover you cannot be sure that the regexp expression you get is the exact same that was used originally... for example

```
/(?:a+)+/
```

and

```
/a+/
```

will be compiled to the same code for matching (expressions are "simplified" before being passed to the code generator).

Most probably you want to find another solution, like saving the original strings before compiling them into regular expression objects.